# section covering all container width on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this container with a section inside, the container background it's white, while the section background its an image. On the site the image don't cover all the width of the container so it have some white background on the sides. Like this:

[image]

I want to cover this white background with the image. Here is the code:

```
    .banner{
    background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;
    padding-top: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    /*box-shadow: 0px 900px rgba(12, 0, 50, 0.6) inset;*/
    box-shadow: 0px 900px rgba(11, 12, 16, 0.6) inset;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="back-white container">
        <section class="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1 class="text-center">
                            Hackeando a Banca
                        </h1>
                        <p class="lead text-center">
                            texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container class have padding-left and padding-right 15px each which causing this change.

Add this and check

```
.no-padding{
   padding-left:0!important;
   padding-right:0!important;
}
```